# Meteor "fiber" error when using Email.send in callback from fs.readFile()

Tags: node.js, email, meteor, fs

I get `Error('Can\'t wait without a fiber')` when I attempt to use `Email.send` inside a callback from `fs.readFile`. I do not get this error if I make the call to `Email.send` directly.

Here's the error:

```
(STDERR) /Users/james/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.8.tvnipv++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:155
  throw new Error('Can\'t wait without a fiber');
        ^
=> Exited with code: 8
(STDERR) Error: Can't wait without a fiber
   at Function.wait (/Users/james/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.8.tvnipv++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:155:9)
   at Object.Future.wait (/Users/james/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.8.tvnipv++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:397:10)
   at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:86:1)
   at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:176:1)
   at email.js:49:17
   at fs.js:272:14
   at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

Here's my JavaScript. Note that I have used a dummy MAIL_URL, to protect the innocent.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var to = 'you@example.com'
  var from = 'me@example.com'
  var title = 'Message'
  var message = "emails/message.html"

  Meteor.call(
    'sendEmail'
  , to
  , from
  , title
  , message
  , callback
  )

  function callback(error, data) {
    console.log(error, data)
  }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN MAIL_URL FOR OUTGOING MESSAGES
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://me%40example.com:PASSWORD@smtp.example.com:25';

    // HACK TO FIND public/ DIRECTORY IN Meteor 1.2.0.1
    var _public = "../../../../../public/"

    var fs = Npm.require('fs');

    Meteor.methods({
      sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, file) {
        var self = this
        var data = file
        check([to, from, subject, file], [String]);

        fs.readFile(_public + file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
            return;
          }

          // Let other method calls from the same client start,
          // running without waiting for the email sending to
          // complete.
          self.unblock();

          Email.send({ // ERROR OCCURS HERE
            to: to,
            from: from,
            subject: subject,
            html: data
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Everything works if I bypass the call to `fs.readFile`, by adding comments as follows:

```
    // fs.readFile(_public + file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    //   if (err) {
    //     console.log('Error: ' + err);
    //     return;
    //   }

      // Let other method calls from the same client start,
      // running without waiting for the email sending to
      // complete.
      self.unblock();

      Email.send({ // ERROR HERE
        to: to,
        from: from,
        subject: subject,
        html: data
      });
    // });
```

Can you help me to understand why a `fiber` is needed in the initial case, and how I should provide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor method calls are always run inside fibers, which provides a synchronous looking API to Node event loop callback style.

You can turn your asynchronous `fs.readFile` call into a synchronous one using `Meteor.wrapAsync` :

```
var fsReadFileSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(fs.readFile, fs);
var data = fsReadFileSync(_public + file, 'utf8');
Email.send(...);
```

EDIT :

> What is the difference between wrapping an async read inside
>   `Meteor.wrapAsync`, and using `fs.readFileSync`? Does the wrapped async
>   read lead to better performance?

`fs.readFileSync` will block Node event loop and is thus only intended to be used for things such as command line utilities.

A wrapped `fs.readFile` on the contrary, will look like it's blocking the event loop to perform I/O tasks synchronously, but under the hood it's still using the non-blocking callback mechanism.

In a webserver application, you really don't want your Node process to get blocked by I/O tasks because it means it could potentially not answer client requests as quickly as it should.

Comment: What is the difference between wrapping an async read inside `Meteor.wrapAsync`, and using `fs.readFileSync`? Does the wrapped async read lead to better performance?